# Bluetooth Peripheral Device Driver? - Droid X

Tags: bluetooth, motorola-droid-x

I'm trying to transfer a picture via bluetooth from my Motorola Droid X - Android 2.2 to my Windows 7 32bit machine.

When I do the normal troubleshooting steps it tells me "No Device Driver found."

Does anyone know where I can find the driver, or what I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my phone to Motorola System Version 2.3.340 and it took care of this issue.

**Steps to update:**

1. Press the menu button from the home screen.
2. Touch `Settings`
3. Touch `About Phone`
4. Touch `System Updates`